# Why doesn't reduce seem to fit when converting from JS to Scala

Tags: javascript, scala, reduce

I have the following JS code...

```
const collection=["Thing1","Thing2"];
const doSomething = (value)=>{
  switch(value){
    case "Thing1":
      return {
        arrayItems: ["Object 1", "Object 2"]
      }
      break;
    default:
      return {
        arrayItems: ["Object 3", "Object 4"]
      }
  }
}
const result = collection.reduce(
  (result, value)=> result.concat(doSomething(value).arrayItems),
  []
);
console.log(result);

// doSomething returns { "arrayItems": ["Object 1", "Object 2"] } for Thing1 
// and { "arrayItems": ["Object 3", "Object 4"] } for Thing 2
// result should be ["Object 1", "Object 2","Object 3", "Object 4"]
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huknwo3d/5/)

I would now like to turn this into a similar Scala reduce like this...

```
val collection = ["Thing 1", "Thing 2"]
val result: Array[...] = collection
                                     .reduce(
    (array: Array[...], value: String) => {
  val objectList = service.doSomething(value)
  if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
    array.concat(objectList)
  } else {
    objectList
  }
});
// doSomething returns { "arrayItems": ["Object 1", "Object 2"] } for Thing1 
// and { "arrayItems": ["Object 3", "Object 4"] } for Thing 2
// result should be ["Object 1", "Object 2","Object 3", "Object 4"]
```

But when I try this I get...

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (Array[...], String) => Array[...]
 required: (java.io.Serializable, java.io.Serializable) => java.io.Serializable
    val result: Array[...] = doSomething(value).reduce((array: Array[...], value: String)=>{
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Update**

I was asked for a background of what I am trying to accomplish, so the basic steps of what I am trying to accomplish are...

1. Take an array of strings
2. Run a reduce function on those strings that produces a Collection of Objects
3. In the reduce function we use the string to call a service which provides a collection of objects
4. These objects are then concatenated with the reduce value and returned

**Updates per Answers**

Thanks guys I didn't know about foldLeft till you brought it up and still working a bit to understand. First here is the working for loop I am trying to avoid...

```
var array : Array[BaseObject] = Array[BaseObject]()
collection.foreach((value: String) => {
  val objectList = doSomething(value).arrayItems
  array = array.concat(objectList)
});
```

I tried this...

```
val array: List[BaseObject] = 
collection.foldLeft(List.empty[BaseObject]){
  (myList, value) => {
    val list : List[BaseObject] = List.from(doSomething(value).arrayList)
    myList ++ list
  }
};
```

But something little must be wrong because when I parse with gson `toJson`, I get....

```
{"head":{...},"next":{}}
```

Where head is one of the Objects but not the whole set.

Comment: It may help if you can explain what you want to do and put complete code _(for example what is inside the **Arrays**)_ - Also, in **Scala** you can assume `null` doesn't exist, it is only there for compatibility with freaking **Java** and **JS**, idiomatic **Scala** code never uses `null`. And **Arrays** are also discouraged, since they are not real collections but rather platform primitives, they are mutable and invariant, prefer **List**, **Vector**, **ArraySeq** or any there real _immutable_ collection.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you for your help, still pretty new to Scala so I will look over the Type thing. I was hoping to avoid a lot of additional code but I will try to add some context to the question.

Comment: Everyone sorry there was a typo in the JS

Comment: Sorry guys I guess I shouldn't have used a simple string example if it was more complicated.

Comment: @JGleason Can you give us a basic definition of `BaseObject` as well as of `doSomething`? Also, it would be good mentioning if you can also change those for more idiomatic alternatives, or if they come from an external source. - Also, you sometimes use `array` and others `collection`, not sure if it is a typo or something that changes the code.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez
Base Object is a very complex object but is basically a model object (case class) but it has sub collections so it contains arrays as well. Also it contains Option items. I can't really release model data given company requirements so I can't provide the entire thing. I can try to refactor to make it a simpler object but I think that will just squeeze the balloon (Like it will help us with BaseObject but then a sub Object of base object may be a problem)

Comment: @JGleason yeah no need to provide all the details, just the relevant fields _(which I hope will be a few and you can put names like foo to protect the data of your company)_. Also, you do not need to put the full definition fo `doSomething` just enough so we can get an idea of what the problem. is Since, in essence, your attempt seems fine _(I would just use `flatMap`, but using `foldLeft` should just work)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I wonder if it isn't a problem with serialization through GSON at this point. That is why I tried to call it out.

Comment: @JGleason I would recommend you to do not use a **Java** library like `GSON` for serializing and deserializing JSONs in **Scala**. We have plenty of mature and more idiomatic options like: `circe`, `play-json`, `uJson`, `jsoniter-scala`, _etc_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez fair enough I can look into that too

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez do any of those work if you are using maven instead of sbt?

Comment: @JGleason yeah, **sbt** and **maven** are just build-tools, and those are just libraries. Both tools provide their own ways to include dependencies but at the end of the day, they are just classes in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer Using FoldLeft as you want to accumulate `String`s over a `List`.

I assumed that your `...` are `String` in the following code :

```
val result: List[String] = myCollection.foldLeft(List.empty[String]){ (myList, value) => {
    val newObject = service.doSomething(value)
    myList :+ newObject
  }
};
```

Also :

- Prefer using immutable collections over mutable ones.
- Usage of `null` is strongly discouraged in Scala. If your List is empty, that won't even be executed.

You can also use placeholders to shorten your code, which will gradually become :

```
val result: List[String] = myCollection.foldLeft(List.empty[String]){ (myList, value) => {
    myList :+ service.doSomething(value)
  }
};
```

then with placeholders

```
val result: List[String] = myCollection.foldLeft(List.empty[String]){ (_, _) => _ :+ service.doSomething(_)
};
```

Comment: Thanks I am still new so I will look through this but this looks really good. FYI as I was making my jsfiddle I noticed that there was a typo but I think you have the idea.

Comment: Fold left looks like it is going to work but my original example was a bit too simplistic.

Comment: I used FoldLeft since the types in your reduce seems to be different. If it was the same type, in a concatenation for example, it would have worked. You call see the signature of reduce and foldleft in the scaladoc :

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#reduce[B%3E:A](op:(B,B)=%3EB):B

Comment: No problem I wasn't clear since I am not sure exactly what is important in Scala yet. So it was my fault thank you so much for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that [`reduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#reduce%5BB%3E:A%5D(op:(B,B)=%3EB):B) will return a value of the same type as the one contained in the collection. So, if you have an **Array** of **Strings** then the result of `reduce` will be a **String** *(oh well, any supertype of **String**, that is why in this case that strange **Serializable** appears)*.
There is a more general version of `reduce` which will allow you to provide any type as output, which is [`foldLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#reduce%5BB%3E:A%5D(op:(B,B)=%3EB):B) that requires an initial value.

Using that, and **Lists** instead of **Arrays** we can write this:

```
def concat(input: List[String])(f: String => List[String]): List[String] =
  input.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) {
    case (acc, str) => acc ++ f(str)
  }
```

However, *appending* to a **List** is somewhat inefficient, so we can rewrite it like this to improve performance.
We will be *prepending* all results and then we will reverse the list to get the output in the expected order:

```
def concat(input: List[String])(f: String => List[String]): List[String] =
  input.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) {
    case (acc, str) => f(str) reverse_::: acc
  }.reverse
```

However, this is a very general operation. We have a collection of some type `A` and a function that returns collections of some type `B` and we want to apply that function to all elements of the original collection and group the results into a single collection of type `B`.
That is the job of [`flatMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#flatMap%5BB%5D(f:A=%3Escala.collection.IterableOnce%5BB%5D):List%5BB%5D) *(which btw it is even more generic; because it works for anything that is a **Monad**, not only a collection)*.

```
def concat(input: List[String])(f: String => List[String]): List[String] =
  input.flatMap(f)
```

I would recommend you to take a look to the **Scaladoc** as well as follow some tutorial, to learn more about all the operations the stdlib provides.
Also, please do not hesitate in asking any questions.

---

You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Lse4N8F6TQ6OfpZUhH8ymQ/2).

Comment: Thanks yours is even blowing my mind further so it may take me a bit to walk through it. I tried posting my first unsuccessful leftFold trial.